# swap some values in an array of objects while maintain sorted others

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say we have an array like this:

```js
[
  {l:A,n:1},
  {l:B,n:2},
  {l:C,n:3},
  {l:D,n:4},
  {l:E,n:5}
]
```

I want to change order of 2 values: C become 5 and D become 2.

If i use a cycle like this to swap values...

```js
const arr = [
  {l:A,n:1},
  {l:B,n:2},
  {l:C,n:3},
  {l:D,n:4},
  {l:E,n:5}
]

const changes = [
  {l:C,n:5},
  {l:D,n:2}
]

changes.forEach(change => {
  const changedI = arr.findIndex( x => x.l == change.l)
  const swappedI = arr.findIndex( x => x.n == change.n)
  const changedN = arr[changedI].n
  arr[changedI].n = change.n
  arr[swappedI].n = changedN
})
```

the result is:

```js
[
  {l:A,n:1},
  {l:B,n:4},
  {l:C,n:5},
  {l:D,n:2},
  {l:E,n:3}
]
```

But i need that the result array is ordered (only) for non changed elements, like this:

```js
[
  {l:A,n:1},
  {l:B,n:3},
  {l:C,n:5},
  {l:D,n:2},
  {l:E,n:4}
]
```

therefore only the changed elements remain fixed, while the elements not expressly changed are rearranged from the smallest to the largest.

I was thinking of doing it with two loops where on the first i swap the slots, and on the second i rearrange only the unchanged elements, but I think there is a faster way, perhaps with a recursion?

Comment: please add the missing code with the mentioned cycle ...

Comment: I don't see how this is a swap, exactly. It seems more like 2 separate priority change operations that have the option of being batched. Also, it appears to be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)--can you provide more context as to what problem you're trying to solve with this structure and operation? Changing priority here has to be O(n) but there exist data structures and algorithms that can handle priority/ordering adjustments more efficiently, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When you say "But i need that the result array maintain the order for non changed elements, like this:" but then finish with "while the elements not expressly changed are rearranged from the smallest to the largest.". These are contradicting statements.

Comment: This is not _swapping_, because you don't want to change the positions of the array elements; this is updating a value given a key. The process is like: Here's an array ("ary"), and here's a change vector ("changes") - update any elements in the array to have the new value in changes where the array element's key (`l`) matches the change vector's key.

Comment: sorry for the wrong terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a single loop approach and store open object who need to get a new number and another for missing numbers.

With

```
change = [['C', 5], ['D', 2]]
```

You get

```
data = [                        v
    { l: 'A', n: 1 }, //        1
    { l: 'B', n: 2 }, //        3
    { l: 'C', n: 3 }, // <- 5   5
    { l: 'D', n: 4 }, // <- 2   2
    { l: 'E', n: 5 }  //        4
]
```

---

With

```
change = [['C', 1]]
```

You get

```
data = [                        v
    { l: 'A', n: 1 }, //        2
    { l: 'B', n: 2 }, //        3
    { l: 'C', n: 3 }, // <- 1   1
    { l: 'D', n: 4 }, //        4
    { l: 'E', n: 5 }  //        5
]
```

```js
const
    data = [
        { l: 'A', n: 1 }, //        2
        { l: 'B', n: 2 }, //        3
        { l: 'C', n: 3 }, // <- 1   1
        { l: 'D', n: 4 }, //        4
        { l: 'E', n: 5 }  //        5
    ],
    //change = [['C', 5], ['D', 2]],
    change = [['C', 1]],
    open = [],
    missing= [];


data.forEach(o => {
    if (change.some(([, v]) => v === o.n)) {
        if (missing.length) o.n = missing.shift();
        else open.push(o);
        return;
    }
    const pair = change.find(([k]) => k === o.l);
    if (pair) {
        if (open.length) open.shift().n = o.n;
        else missing.push(o.n);
        o.n = pair[1];
        return;
    }
    open.push(o);
    open.shift().n = o.n;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @StephenP it is just an unused variable for destructuring.

Comment: can it be written [,v] in es6 or typescript?

Comment: I can't understand what "if (open.length) open.shift().n = o.n;" is for... why assign value to the shifted object? after the shift array length become 0 and shifted object is lost, what am i missing?

Comment: is is a stack for objects who need a new number.

Comment: try change = [['C',1]]

Answer (score 0):

if you do know the data in your array and where exactly you want to change or update, you can access the specific index which will return an object and access the object and update the value check below

```
var dataOne = [
  { l: 'A', n: 1 },
  { l: 'B', n: 3 },
  { l: 'C', n: 5 },
  { l: 'D', n: 2 },
  { l: 'E', n: 4 }
];
dataOne[0]['n'] = 99

console.log( dataOne );
 // [
 // { l: 'A', n: 99 },
 // { l: 'B', n: 3 },
 // { l: 'C', n: 5 },
 // { l: 'D', n: 2 },
 // { l: 'E', n: 4 }
   // ];
```

Comment: values for each letter must be from 1 to 5 (in this example), they must no repeat and should be sorted for non changed elements